# Java 21 on Raspberry Pi 5

Tags: java, arm

I'm not able to install Java 21 on Raspberry Pi 5. I download ARM versions from openJDK and Oracle, but both don't work for me.

When typing ./java it prints: "**No such file or directory**" (*I'm sure I'm in the right directory*)

I cannot find any repository I can use to install Java 21 and I need newer version of Java than 17 for my projects written in Java 21.

**file ./java** output

> ./java: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV),
> dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for
> GNU/Linux 3.7.0, not stripped

**ldd ./java** output:

> java is "*not a dynamic executable*"

Do you have any idea how I can install Java 21 on Raspberry Pi 5?

**How to reproduce:**

- **OpenJDK**: From website (https://jdk.java.net/21/) I downloaded version for Linux / AArch64, unpacked it and try to run java
  executable from unpacked directory bin/java using java command inside
  of the mentioned directory
- **Oracle JDK**: I download from website (https://www.oracle.com/pl/java/technologies/downloads/) version for
  ARM64 Compressed Archive and did exactly as with OpenJDK version.

Distribution is the default for Raspberry Pi 5: **Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit (based on Debian)**

**Output for** *find / -name java -type f -exec ls -l {} ; 2>/dev/null*:

> bloodlex@raspberrypi:~/Download/jdk-21.0.1/bin $ find / -name java
> -type f -exec ls -l {} ; 2>/dev/null
> -rwxr-xr-x 1 bloodlex bloodlex 70792 10-05 15:44 /home/bloodlex/Download/jdk-21.0.1/bin/java

**Output for** *file /bin/ls*:

> bloodlex@raspberrypi:~/Download/jdk-21.0.1/bin $ file /bin/ls /bin/ls:
> ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically
> linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3,
> BuildID[sha1]=73a3ba02d9f4bf3632cbebe139c6a844ca5076d3, for GNU/Linux
> 3.2.0, stripped

**Output for** *uname -a*

> bloodlex@raspberrypi:~/Download/jdk-21.0.1/bin $ uname -a Linux
> raspberrypi 6.1.0-rpi6-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.1.58-1+rpt2
> (2023-10-27) aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: sudo chmod +rx ./java 
./java 
unable to execute ./java: No such file or directory

Comment: How do you do the installation?

Comment: I download the ARM version from openJDK/Oracle, unpack it and try to run ./java from bin category

Comment: Add exact steps in the question. and show the result of command: `find / -name java -type f -exec ls -l {} \; 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Are you using a distro with 32-bit userspace?

Comment: As well as responding to the other comments' requests, please also add `file /bin/ls`  for comparison with your existing `file ./java`. (I'm sure you will, but please remember to add all your updates to the question, ensuring as you do that the result is still nicely readable.)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've included all the outputs to the main question. Do you have any other ideas? I'm not sure about the question with 32-bit userspace, could you be more precise @TomYan?

Comment: Well, it basically refers to the fact that we see `32-bit` in your `file /bin/ls` output (but `aarch64` in the `uname` output). You'll need a 32-bit build of JDK/JRE (if that's available from anywhere).

Comment: How is that possible? By default 64 bit raspberry system has some 32 bit components installed?

Comment: Not some, but everything but the kernel (hence "userspace"). Not exactly sure why but I recalled as well that's what they decided to have instead of a "wholly 64-bit" system.

Comment: Okay, I see now. So maybe I'd go better with Ubuntu server 64 bit for ARM?

Comment: Well, IMO whether a distro is "better" than another is a subjective matter. If you can't find a 32-bit build Java (or if it just doesn't support 32-bit ARM at all), and yet you really need it on the Pi, maybe. Can also consider having a 64-bit chroot / container, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to wipe the SD card from Raspberry (the one that I received in a package with the device) and downloaded a new official Raspberry Pi 5 64 bit image. Now Java works as expected with ARM 64 bit version without any problems. It seems that now also userspace is 64 bit as it should.

So the solution in my case is not to use the default operating system that you can find on the SD card delivered with your Raspberry Pi 5. I recommend to download the official tool and operating system and do it yourself.